# Azure Powershell (Az module) get public IP address

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

With the new Az module for Azure, does anyone have the syntax for getting the public IP address of an Azure VM using the name?
The commandlet `Get-AzPublicIpAddress` has no argument for the VM name, only the IP object name

This works, but I'm not using the machine name here, it's the name of the IP object itself:

```
$CurrentIp = (Get-AzPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName 'RG1' -Name 'MyVMname-ip').IpAddress
```

I can't figure out how to just get it from the VM object i.e. this doesn't work:

```
Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName 'RG1' -Name 'MyVMname' | Get-AzPublicIpAddress
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I know, it's impossible to get the VM public IP through just one PowerShell [`Get-AzPublicIpAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/get-azpublicipaddress?view=azps-1.3.0) with the VM name. And the public IP in Azure is an individual resource associated with the network interface, not the VM.

As you see, there no parameter for VM name to get the public IP in that document. But you can get the public IP through a PowerShell script just with the VM name and resource group name. The script shows below:

```
$vm = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName yourRG -Name vmNamme
$nic = $vm.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces[0].Id.Split('/') | select -Last 1
$publicIpName =  (Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName yourRG -Name $nic).IpConfigurations.PublicIpAddress.Id.Split('/') | select -Last 1
$publicIpAddress = (Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName yourRG -Name $publicIpName).IpAddress
Write-Output $vmName $publicIpAddress
```

Or just one CLI command to get the public IP like this:

```
az vm show -d -g yourRG -n vmName --query publicIps
```

Comment: Wow, that's a lot more complicated than the old AzureRM command.....thanks, I think...

Comment: @Scepticalist I think it also cannot achieve through the old AzureRM module with just one PowerShell command.

Comment: @Scepticalist Any more questions? Or if it's helpful you can accept it as the answer.

Comment: $PublicIpAddress = (az vm list-ip-addresses --resource-group "$ResourceGroupName" --name "$VMName" --query '[].virtualMachine.network.publicIpAddresses[0].ipAddress' --output tsv)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a more thorough answer, as this uses PowerShell Az as the original question intended to use.  In addition, it leverages Generic.List[psobject] which is useful for later playing with the  data.

```
$rg = 'RgName'
$Ips = Get-AzNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName $rg
$vmDetails = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.List[psobject]"
foreach ($instance in $Ips){
    $Vm = ($instance.VirtualMachine).Id.Split('/') | select -Last 1
    $PrivateIp = $instance.IpConfigurations.PrivateIpAddress
    $PublicIp = (Get-AzPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name ($instance.IpConfigurations.publicIpAddress.Id.Split('/') | select -Last 1)).IpAddress
    $obj = New-Object psobject -Property @{
        ResourceGroupName = $rg
        VmName = $vm
        PrivateIp = $PrivateIp
        PublicIp = $PublicIp
    }
    $vmDetails.Add($obj)
}
Write-Output $vmDetails
```

This isn't as straight forward as Az CLI unfortunately but a good script to have regardless for Az modules.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on Andrew Harris' answer, it filters out network interfaces not attached to machines and accounts for VMs that don't have a public IP:

```
function Get-VmIP {
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Returns the IP addresses for all VMs in the current subscription.
    #>
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param()

    $Interfaces = Get-AzNetworkInterface

    foreach ($Interface in $Interfaces) {

        if ($Interface.VirtualMachine) {
            $VMName = $Interface.VirtualMachine.Id.split('/')[-1]
            $PrivateIP = $Interface.IpConfigurations.PrivateIpAddress

            $PublicIP = if ($Interface.IpConfigurations.publicIpAddress) {
                Get-AzPublicIpAddress -Name ($instance.IpConfigurations.publicIpAddress.Id.Split('/')[-1]).IpAddress
            }     
        
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                VMName    = $VMName
                RGName    = $Interface.ResourceGroupName
                PrivateIP = $PrivateIP
                PublicIP  = $PublicIP
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a corrected version of the Mark Wragg's script earlier in this thread:

```
function Get-VmIP {
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Returns the IP addresses for all VMs in the current subscription.
#>
[cmdletbinding()]
param()

$Interfaces = Get-AzNetworkInterface

foreach ($Interface in $Interfaces) {

    if ($Interface.VirtualMachine) {
        $VMName = $Interface.VirtualMachine.Id.split('/')[-1]

        $PrivateIP = $Interface.IpConfigurations.PrivateIpAddress
        $PublicIpAddressConfig = $Interface.IpConfigurations.publicIpAddress
        
        $PublicIP = $null
        $pconfigname = $null
        if ($PublicIpAddressConfig) {
            $pconfigname = $PublicIpAddressConfig.Id.Split('/')[-1]
            $PublicIP = (Get-AzPublicIpAddress -Name $pconfigname).IpAddress
        }     
    
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            VMName    = $VMName
            RGName    = $Interface.ResourceGroupName
            PrivateIP = $PrivateIP
            PublicIP  = $PublicIP
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer uses AzureRM PowerShell module which is now obsoleted by Az module:

```
$VM = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -VMName $VMName
$NetworkInterfaceName = $VM.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces[0].Id.Split('/')[-1]
$NetworkInterface = Get-AzNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName $VM.ResourceGroupName -Name $NetworkInterfaceName
$PublicIpAddressName = $NetworkInterface.IpConfigurations.PublicIpAddress.Id.Split('/')[-1]
$PublicIpAddress = Get-AzPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName $VM.ResourceGroupName -Name $PublicIpAddressName
Write-Host "IP: $($PublicIpAddress.IpAddress), FQDN: $($PublicIpAddress.DnsSettings.Fqdn)"
```

Answer (score -1):

Scope of the script is within an Azure subscription.

Below is the one-liner script which returns Name, PublicIpAllocaitonMethod(It's basically the type of the IP address whether it's a Static or Public IP)  and the IpAddress properties of all the Network interfaces in a subscription.

```
(Get-AzNetworkInterface ).IpConfigurations.PublicIpAddress.Id | Foreach-Object -Process {$_.Split('/')| select -Last 1} | Foreach-Object -Process {Get-AzPublicIpAddress -Name $_} | Format-List Name, PublicIpAllocationMethod,IpAddress
```

If we remove the last statement Format-List it will display all the properties of the network interfaces that are having public IP addresses.

Comment: Doesn't print the VM name, just the name of the NIC